# How to get a variable to save in all Scenes in SpritKit swift Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a variable that I made. I made it so that all Scenes (there's three) know what it is. I called it "money" and attached an Interger to it. But it won't save. So when I go my second scene to add $20 to the money which now the money should have $20 in it. When I go back to the first scene to check it its not there it says there are zero dollars. Does anyone know how to make a money system that all Scenes can recognize and add money to that "Money" variable. Kind of like how you would save a high score and know matter what even if you close the app the high score is still saved

Comment: Is the `Money` variable local to one scene?

Comment: Know it's in the top class so all scene know what it is. But I just doesn't save

Comment: Like lets say if you earn some coins and won't to save it and be able to add to it in other words deposit more?

Comment: By save do you mean that when the user leaves the app and enters again?

Comment: Know like kind of I'm trying to use NSUserdefualts to save it but it's not.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Sure give me a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to manage global variables is a `Singleton` class.

The class gets instantiated the first time it's called and persists during the life time of the application.

The class contains the mentioned variable `money` as well as a dummy string variable `somethingElse`. You can add as many variables as you need.

```
class DefaultsManager {

  // MARK: - Variables

  var money : Int = 0
  var somethingElse : String  = ""

  // MARK: - Shared Instance

  class var sharedManager : DefaultsManager {
    struct Singleton {
      static let instance = DefaultsManager()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
  }

  init()
  {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let defaultValues = ["money" : 0, "somethingElse" : ""];
    defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
  }

  func readDefaults()
  {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    money = defaults.integerForKey("money")
    somethingElse = defaults.stringForKey("somethingElse")!
  }

  func saveDefaults()
  {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setInteger(money, forKey:"money")
    defaults.setObject(somethingElse, forKey:"somethingElse")
    defaults.synchronize()
  }

}
```

The class is accessible from everywhere.

- Get the shared instance

  ```
  let manager = DefaultsManager.sharedManager
  ```
- Get the value of the variable `money`

  ```
  var currentDeposit = manager.money
  ```
- Read and write the variables from user defaults

  ```
  manager.readDefaults()
  manager.saveDefaults()
  ```

If you add more variables, you have to register them in `init` and to add lines to read and save them according to the other variables.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need thanks everybody!

Comment: Wait I don't think I'm putting it i the right place where exactly do you put it or do you make another swift file

Comment: I'd recommend to use a separate file